# Why is it not possible to establish a connection between these servers?

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, ping, icmp

I have the problem that my two servers (master, worker) can not connect to each other. However, connections outside e.g. "google.com" are possible. I have already tried to allow all ICMP connections, which are otherwise forbidden in the prerouting. However, this has not helped at all.

When pinging from my master to the worker I get the following output:

`3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2035ms`

nslookup also only returns results via the IP and not via the hostname, which makes me wonder even more. However, also a ping via the IP remains unsuccessful.

My `/etc/hosts/` file is configured as follows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx     Master
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx     Worker
```

These are the Iptables rules from the master:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue May  2 11:35:23 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcpmss ! --mss 536:65535 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p icmp -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 224.0.0.0/3 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 169.254.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 240.0.0.0/5 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -f -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May  2 11:35:23 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue May  2 11:35:23 2023
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:anti-port-scan - [0:0]
-A INPUT -s IFCS-Worker-01/32 -d IFCS-Master-01/32 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 6443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 2379:2380 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 10250 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 10257 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 10259 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 179 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 2379 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 4789 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 91.218.66.183 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "FW: INPUT DROP: "
-A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 6 --connlimit-mask 32 --connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 10/sec --limit-burst 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 303/sec --limit-burst 24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 20 --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -s IFCS-Master-01/32 -d IFCS-Worker-01/32 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 179 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 4789 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 91.218.66.183 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "FW: OUTPUT DROP: "
-A anti-port-scan -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK RST -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 2 -j RETURN
-A anti-port-scan -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May  2 11:35:23 2023
```

These are the Iptables rules from the worker:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue May  2 11:35:23 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcpmss ! --mss 536:65535 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p icmp -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 224.0.0.0/3 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 169.254.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 240.0.0.0/5 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -f -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May  2 11:35:23 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue May  2 11:35:23 2023
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:anti-port-scan - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 10250 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3000:32767 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 179 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 2379 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 4789 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "FW: INPUT DROP: "
-A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 6 --connlimit-mask 32 --connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 10/sec --limit-burst 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 303/sec --limit-burst 24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 20 --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 179 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 4789 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "FW: OUTPUT DROP: "
-A anti-port-scan -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK RST -m limit --limit 1/sec --limit-burst 2 -j RETURN
-A anti-port-scan -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue May  2 11:35:23 2023
```

Comment: You told both of them to drop ICMP packets... such as pings... (and other important ones such as Path MTU Exceeded). What did you expect?